# The linux service that I am trying to run does not terminate and restarts even with Restart=no in systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, udev, services

```
    Jul 01 16:47:17 server start.sh[21353]: Operation successfully completed
Jul 01 16:47:17 server start.sh[21353]: Saving 5 titles into directory ./raw
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: 5 titles saved
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: Copy complete. 5 titles saved.
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: title_t00.mkv
Jul 01 17:17:49 server start.sh[21353]: MOVIE
Jul 01 17:17:50 server systemd[1]: Started DVD-Ripper.
Jul 01 17:17:50 server start.sh[8906]: MakeMKV v1.14.4 linux(x64-release) started
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: Failed to open disc
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: Movie.mkv
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: rm: cannot remove '*.mkv': No such file or directory
```

The service keeps restarting as shown, even if I have Restart=no in the .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=DVD-Ripper

[Service]
ExecStart=/mnt/DVD/MakeMKV/start.sh
KillMode=mixed
SendSIGKILL=no
User=root
Restart=no
```

Does anyone know why this might happen?

---

This is from the log using journalctl -u DVD-Ripper

```
Jul 01 16:46:30 server start.sh[21353]: MakeMKV v1.14.4 linux(x64-release) started
Jul 01 16:46:33 server start.sh[21353]: Using direct disc access mode
Jul 01 16:46:39 server start.sh[21353]: Title #1 was added (25 cell(s), 0:47:07)
Jul 01 16:46:40 server start.sh[21353]: Title #1/0/1 was added (5 cell(s), 0:24:19)
Jul 01 16:46:41 server start.sh[21353]: Title #1/0/2 was added (5 cell(s), 0:24:18)
Jul 01 16:46:41 server start.sh[21353]: Title #2 was added (25 cell(s), 0:47:07)
Jul 01 16:46:41 server start.sh[21353]: Title #3 was added (5 cell(s), 0:24:19)
Jul 01 16:46:41 server start.sh[21353]: Title #4 was added (5 cell(s), 0:24:18)
Jul 01 16:47:08 server start.sh[21353]: Title #7 was added (5 cell(s), 0:04:59)
Jul 01 16:47:08 server start.sh[21353]: Title #8 was added (5 cell(s), 0:04:59)
Jul 01 16:47:08 server start.sh[21353]: Title #9 has length of 36 seconds which is less tha
Jul 01 16:47:08 server start.sh[21353]: Title #10 has length of 53 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:09 server start.sh[21353]: Title #11 has length of 26 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:09 server start.sh[21353]: Title #12 was added (1 cell(s), 0:02:22)
Jul 01 16:47:09 server start.sh[21353]: Title #13 has length of 99 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:09 server start.sh[21353]: Title #14 has length of 25 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:10 server start.sh[21353]: Title #15 has length of 111 seconds which is less t
Jul 01 16:47:10 server start.sh[21353]: Title #16 has length of 62 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:10 server start.sh[21353]: Title #17 has length of 33 seconds which is less th
Jul 01 16:47:10 server start.sh[21353]: Title 1 in VTS 3 is equal to title 4 and was skippe
Jul 01 16:47:11 server start.sh[21353]: Title 2 in VTS 3 is equal to title 4 and was skippe
Jul 01 16:47:11 server start.sh[21353]: Title 3 in VTS 3 is equal to title 4 and was skippe
Jul 01 16:47:11 server start.sh[21353]: Title 4 in VTS 5 is equal to title 3 and was skippe
Jul 01 16:47:17 server start.sh[21353]: Operation successfully completed
Jul 01 16:47:17 server start.sh[21353]: Saving 5 titles into directory ./raw
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: 5 titles saved
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: Copy complete. 5 titles saved.
Jul 01 17:17:48 server start.sh[21353]: title_t00.mkv
Jul 01 17:17:49 server start.sh[21353]: MOVIE
Jul 01 17:17:50 server systemd[1]: Started DVD-Ripper.
Jul 01 17:17:50 server start.sh[8906]: MakeMKV v1.14.4 linux(x64-release) started
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: Failed to open disc
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: MOVIE.mkv
Jul 01 17:17:52 server start.sh[8906]: rm: cannot remove '*.mkv': No such file or directory
```

This is the ExecStart in the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/DVD/MakeMKV/
makemkvcon mkv disc:0 all ./raw
cd ./raw
file=$(ls -S | head -1)
echo $file
mv "$file" ./final
rm *.mkv
mv ./final/* ./
DVD_NAME=$(udevadm info -n sr1 -q property | sed -n 's/^ID_FS_LABEL=//p')
echo $DVD_NAME
mv ./*.mkv ./$DVD_NAME.mkv
eject sr1
```

Here is the trigger:

```
KERNEL=="sr1", ACTION=="change",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}="1", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_STATE}!="blank", RUN+="/mnt/DVD/MakeMKV/trigger.sh"
```

trigger.sh contains:

```
systemctl start DVD-Ripper
```

EDIT-
The UDEV trigger triggers both when inserted and removed. How would I modify the trigger to only check for dvd inserts?

Comment: You seem to show a log of the script running under two different PIDs; could you show the output from `sudo journalctl -u DVD-Ripper` to get systemd's perspective on things?

Comment: You'll want to [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/527902/edit) instead of commenting or answering, as the formatting is limited, and the right place for updates is in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks! I edited the question.

Comment: @muru It starts off of a udev trigger. When a DVD is inserted. I am trying to rip a dvd when it is inserted.

Comment: @muru Thanks I added it.

Comment: I wonder if ejecting qualifies as a change for udev.

Comment: @muru I just edited the question. It does trigger it twice. How would I make it so it would only trigger when inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I ended up fixing this problem by modifying my trigger.sh file to this and left the udev trigger the same. This is what is in trigger.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/DVD/MakeMKV/
info=$(blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sr1)
type=$(echo 'udf')
echo $info
echo $type
if [ "$info" == "$type" ]
then
systemctl start DVD-Ripper
fi
```

It checks the type and checks if it is a udf. $info returns blank if no dvd is inserted and equals "udf" when inserted, so when inserted, it makes the if statement true.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Udev allows you to react to hardware events, in this case the `ACTION` can be `add`, `remove`, `change`.

You have `ACTION=="change"` which will fire when a DVD is inserted or ejected.

Try the following rule:

```
KERNEL=="sr1", ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_DVD}="1", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_STATE}!="blank", RUN+="/mnt/DVD/MakeMKV/trigger.sh"
```

Comment: Does inserting a dvd trigger an ACTION="add" event, I didn't see it when I checked